# Get Button Inputs in Java

Tags: java, joystick, gamepad

so im writing an application that is supposed to use 6 game pads as input. i have found alot of documentation about a library called JINPUT. but the official download link gives me a 404 error. it would be awesome if someone here knew an alternative i could use. or knew a good download link. thanks!

Comment: Use some other download site, like this [one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjinput10jar.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JInput can be found there :

http://java.net/projects/jinput

You can use SVN to get it :

http://java.net/projects/jinput/sources/svn/show/trunk?rev=252

There are some tutorials around the web you could use.

Comment: i did find that page, but the download redirects me to this page http://www.newdawnsoftware.com/resources/jinput/

Comment: @user2218815 - check the link I posted

Comment: @user2218815 if I were you, I would use SVN to get it. This way, you're sure to get latest release. I usually don't trust download links, only downloads from the trunk SVN or Git repo.

Comment: @R.J : if you look at the build.xml in the SVN trunk, you can see : <property name="api.version" value="2.0.6"/> ... Your link allow the download of version 1.0 ...

Comment: AHHH SVN i totally forgot, thanks i will definitely do that. thanks guys

Comment: @user2218815 if it was helpful, don't forget to validate the answer for the next guy who will be looking for JInput :)